# Post request with only query parameters using RestTemplate POST method

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to call an API using POST method. There is no body in it and all parameters in the URL only.

This is how I am building request to call via **okHttpClient** version :

```
Request requestToken = new Request.Builder()
                .url(TOKEN_GEN_API_URL + ConfigConstants.TOKEN_CLIENT_ID_PARAM
                        + TOKEN_CLIENT_ID_PARAM_VALUE + ConfigConstants.TOKEN_CLINET_SECRET_PARAM
                        + TOKEN_CLIENT_SECRET_PARAM_VALUE + ConfigConstants.TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE_PARAM
                        + TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE_PARAM_VALUE)
                .post(requestBody)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .build();
```

**ConfigConstants Class :**

```
public class ConfigConstants {
    
    public static final String TOKEN_CLIENT_ID_PARAM = "?client_id=";
    public static final String TOKEN_CLINET_SECRET_PARAM = "&client_secret=";
    public static final String TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE_PARAM = "&grant_type=";
}
```

This would create URL something like this :

```
<endpoint>?client_id=...&client_secret=..&grant_type=..
```

Now, I am trying call this via RestTemplate, I think it would less complicated in that. But, I am not sure how to build this request without any body.

```
@RestController
public class TokenRestAPI {
    
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TokenRestAPI.class);

    @Value("${TOKEN_CLIENT_SEC_PARAM_VALUE}")
    private String TOKEN_CLIENT_SECRET_PARAM_VALUE;

    @Value("${TOKEN_CLIENT_ID_PARAM_VALUE}")
    private String TOKEN_CLIENT_ID_PARAM_VALUE;

    @Value("${TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE_PARAM_VALUE}")
    private String TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE_PARAM_VALUE;


    @Value("${TOKEN_GEN_API_URL}")
    private String TOKEN_GEN_API_URL;
    
    
    @PostMapping("/")
    public void getAuthToken() {
        
        ResponseEntity<TokenPOJO> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(TOKEN_GEN_API_URL, request, TokenPOJO.class);
        
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to send a body, just pass null as the request object:

```
ResponseEntity<TokenPOJO> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(TOKEN_GEN_API_URL, null, TokenPOJO.class);
```

you will still have to either build up the URL or use the parameters. The last you can do by putting variables in your url string like:

```
String url = "http://example.com?foo={bar}"
```

and pass a map with the variable name as key and the parameter value as the value.